# Using Loop to show two or more indication when conditions will met

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I want to create an alert. My indicator should show an alert when the first indicator shows a signal and if the second indicator shows two or more time signals in that time.

My script work fine when i use only to show one time indication

`alertcondition(bsignal == true and long == true, title="Buy Signal  generated", message="Buy Signal generated")`

But i need to show indication every time when the condition is met so i search it on google and use this while loop, but its not working... Error show "**Syntax error at input 'true'.**"

```
a = bsignal 
b = long 
while true
    if (a == true) and (b == true)
       alertcondition(true, title="Buy Signal generated", message="Buy Signal generated")
   else
      alertcondition(false)
```

Please suggest what should i do?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you need to trigger an alert in a loop, you should use the `alert()` function. `alertcondition()` cannot be called in a local scope.

However, I am not sure if you need a loop. Your script will be executed on each bar and you will have access to historical data. You can check if a condition was `true` some time ago with the `ta.barssince()` function. Or you can use the [history referencing operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Operators.html#history-referencing-operator). This way you can check historical data and avoid a loop.

Comment: Suppose my 1st indicator show the Long which covers the 10 candles, and my 2nd indicator show three time Long within that 10 candles.

so if i use the below code then it works on first time when both conditions meet. But if my 2nd indicator show second time "Long" and my first condition is also true then my script will never work.

`alertcondition(bsignal == true and long == true, title="Buy Signal  generated", message="Buy Signal generated")`

So I think I need to use a loop.

Comment: My main issue is that loop script not working. Error show **"Syntax error at input 'true' "**